# Opening a site on Firefox using webbrowser module

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the 'webbrowser' module to access a website on my Firefox. After going through some of the posts on this site, I found that this piece of code works for most of them:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.get('firefox').open('www.google.com')
```

However, I get the following error:

```
raise Error("could not locate runnable browser")
Error: could not locate runnable browser
```

What seems to be wrong with my code?

PS: Firefox is not my default browser.

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: Windows is what I'm using.

Comment: Your code works on my Mac when adding `http://` in front of the URL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
webbrowser._tryorder
```

this shows you valid browsers you can pass get function. Firefox is in this list for me as linux user.

If firefox is not that list, try register it manually:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.register('firefox', None, webbrowser.GenericBrowser('firefox'), 1)
webbrowser.get('firefox').open('https://www.google.com')
```

Of course I can not guaranteed that this solution work, because I could not try it on windows.

Comment: What's the difference between GenericBrowser and BackgroundBrowser which is suggested in  the next answer?

Comment: @Jay BackgroundBrowser browser inherited from GenericBrowser. Difference is that it opens browser  in background

Answer (score 4):

On windows, you might have to pass the file path to the Mozilla Firefox executable. For me, this worked (the _tryorder print is just to check):

```
import webbrowser
ffpath = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe'
print webbrowser._tryorder
webbrowser.register('firefox', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(ffpath), 1)
print webbrowser._tryorder
ff = webbrowser.get('firefox')
ff.open("http://www.google.com")
```

Comment: late to the party and here's my 2 cents:
on python 3.7, I had to remove '1' that has been passed as an argument in the register function to get it working.

Comment: @SumitKumar what does that '1' do?

Comment: @Jay 1 is the new tryorder for that browser.

Comment: I don't know what version of Python this was written for, but in 3.8 you need to change the `1` for `preferred=True`.